# Saving classification report results to csv for every classifier in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn

So I am testing 3 sklearn ml classifiers for a dataset and need to save all results for every ml classifier in separate csv files. Is there a possible way to do this? My code is given below:

```
models= {'Random Forest':RandomForestClassifier(),
'LogisticRegression': LogisticRegression()}
'ExtraTrees': ExtraTreesClassifier()} 

for i, v in models.items():
    v.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    print('model ',i,' trained.')
    v_pred= v.predict(X_test)
    print('model ',i,' predictions made')
    v_pred= pd.DataFrame(v_pred, columns=Y_train.columns)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, v_pred)
    confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(Y_test, v_pred)
    classification = classification_report(Y_test, v_pred)

    print ("Model Accuracy: ", '{}%'.format(np.round(accuracy, 3) * 100)) 
    print()
    print("Confusion Matrix:" "\n", confusion_matrix)
    print()
    print("Classification Report:" "\n", classification)
```

Any modifications/advice/solutions will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can plugin the following code in your for loop, where you are evaluating each model.

```
Y_test=[1,2,3,4]
v_pred=[1,3,3,4]
i="Random Forest"
result=pd.DataFrame({"Y_test":Y_test,"v_pred":v_pred})
result.to_csv(i)
```